# Web3js Smart Contract interaction and Signing

Tags: javascript, typescript, smartcontracts, web3js

I can interact with a smart contract when using a local node(ganache).
But when I try to interact with a public node with the following method, I get `sender account not recognized`

```
const web3 = new Web3(new HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
const wallet = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(wallet);
web3.eth.defaultAccount = wallet.address;

const contractObj = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
const receipt = await contractObj.methods.NameofTheMethod(x).send({ 
  from: myAddress,
  gasLimit: value
});
```

How can I make it working without third party wallets like `@truffle/HDWalletProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

Your local node knows the private key of the sender => is able to sign the transaction (on the local node).

The 3rd party node doesn't know the private key - that's why you got the error message.

You can pass the private key to the app so it can sign the transaction locally, and send the already signed transaction to the node without revealing the private key.

---

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const provider = new HDWalletProvider({
    privateKeys: ["0x<your_private_key>"],
    providerOrUrl: "https://<node_provider_url>/"
});
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider

---

Without using external package, you can pass the private key using the `wallet.add()` method.

```
const web3 = new Web3("https://<node_provider_url>/");
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add("0x<your_private_key>");
```

Docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I asked a solution without `@truffle/HDWalletProvider`

Comment: @dreygur I missed that part. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks again! But as you can see I have tried in `web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add()` way and it didn't work. Should I sign the transaction manually?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the manual way of signing the transaction and sending it to node. Like this:

```
const web3 = new Web3(new HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
const { address } = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
const data = await contract.methods.nameOfTheMethod(x).encodeABI();
const transaction = {
  data,
  from: address,
  gas: '0x6DDD0',
  gasLimit: value,
};
const signedTrx = await web3.eth.signTransaction(transaction, privateKey);
const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTrx.rawTransaction);
console.log(receipt);
```

Don't know if it's the only way except using `@truffle/HDWalletProvider`